# Can't access a variable changed before in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

for my application, I want to change the value named cool, that has the value 2 by default. I do it with this code :

```
public void showJSON (String response){
   String aaa= "yes";

    if (aaa.equals("yes")) {
       cool= 1;
   } else {
       cool= 2;
   }  }
```

The problem I have with this code is that, when I want to get that value just after, it always give me the default value (the value : 2) and not the one change :

```
 @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu add){


   if (cool == 2){

       //Adding our menu to toolbar
       //noir
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add, add);
   } else {
       //vert
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.alreadyadded, add);
   }


   return true;   }
```

I verified that my value in the first code can change, and yes, it works, but the cool value even if it changed before, still has the default value after. 
Thank yu for your help !

Comment: this is because before you changed the cool value `onCreateOptionsMenu()` was created

Comment: No, my  onCreateOptionsMenu() is created after I canged the value

Comment: post your code please where did you change

Comment: It is the code I've posted, it is the first one, where 'cool' get the value 2 or 1

Comment: where is the showJson method?

Comment: Just before, there is nothing between the ShowJSON and the onCreateOptionsMenu

Comment: post the code where you called the showJson() METHOD

Comment: I called this method in the onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) , it is always called.

Comment: are you getting the response from somewhere?

Comment: Yeah, from a php code, but the code is good. For example when I want the 'cool' to have the value 1 it has this value and when I want it to have the value 2 it works too. But I only get this good value on the ShowJSON method, when i am in the other method, the value is always th one in default.

Comment: code is good.. i know but your onCreateOptionsMenu is getting called first..

Comment: response calling is done in background thread..

Comment: So how am I supposed to change that?

Comment: i am writing the answer..

Comment: Thanks man, really :)

Comment: i have written try it..tell me if you have any problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `showJson()` would be like this..

```
public void showJSON (String response){

     String aaa= "yes";

     if (aaa.equals("yes")) {
         cool= 1;
    } else {
       cool= 2;
       }    
  this.menu.clear(); //Make a field menu Variable like Menu menu;
  this.onCreateOptionsMenu(this.menu);
 }
```

And your `onCreateOptionsMenu` would be like this..

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu add){

    this.menu = add ;

    if (cool == 2){

         //Adding our menu to toolbar
         //noir
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add, add);
    } else {
       //vert
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.alreadyadded, add);
    }


    return true;   }
```

Comment: make a field variable `Menu menu;` at the top above `onCreate()` and report.. @nfgvnudvegnv3

Comment: is it fine now?

Comment: Thanks you, it now works ! I will see how it works later because I don't seem to understand how it change things, but really, thank you !!

Comment: happy to help :)

Comment: Ahah thanks for helping me, I had never seen that in any other questions before. Have a good day man :)